# Is it possible to shuffle a list in Redis?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to shuffle a list in Redis (server-side)?

Comment: What about consulting official site first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with version 2.4.

With the future 2.6 release, perhaps it could be implemented with Lua server-side scripting, but I don't expect this to be really efficient.

I don't know about your use case, but if you can live with unicity for your items, you can perhaps replace the list by a set and use the SPOP command. Instead of shuffling your list and removing items in a specific order, you can use an unordered container and pop out random items.

Comment: If you were to use this approach, it might be useful to first create a copy of the set so that you still have your original set after you're finished `SPOP`ing. You can do this with [SUNIONSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/sunionstore)

Comment: In version 2.6 there is [srandmember](http://redis.io/commands/srandmember) _"If count is bigger than the number of elements inside the Set, the command will only return the whole set without additional elements."_
So one way is perhaps to call this command with a big number, clear and repopulate the list with the random return.

Answer (score 2):

No.

For a full list of available commands use http://redis.io/commands#list